# How to instantiate Ionic element with test-library

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, testing-library, angular-testing-library

I have an Angular component which has an `ion-searchbar`. I'm using a template ref on the `ngAfterViewInit` hook to handle the searcbar native input through the Ionic's `getInputElement()` method:

// my-component.html

```
 <ion-searchbar
      ...other inputs
      #ionSearchbar
 ></ion-searchbar>
```

// my-component.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   //...other inputs
   @ViewChild("ionSearchbar") ionSearchBarRef: IonSearchbar

   constructor() {}

    async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const ionSearchBarNativeInput = await this.ionSearchBarRef.getInputElement()
    //... do something with the native input
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run any test of that component I get the following error:

```
        const ionSearchBarNativeInput = await this.ionSearchBarRef.getInputElement();
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInputElement')
    at MyComponent.ngAfterViewInit
```

The tests pass though, but I guess I have to mock somehow the `ion-searchbar` in order to allow the test run the logic inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Any idea of how to do this with `"@testing-library/angular`?

Thanks in advance!